# Android usb serial setting custom baud rate

Tags: android, serial-port, usb

I know how to set standard baud rates with the method UsbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer().
But how can I set a non standard baud rate, like 3000000 or 4000000?
This topic is little documented and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it:

```
controlTransfer(65, 30, 0, 0, new byte[]{-64, -58, 45, 0}, 0, 4, 5000);
```

(this is for 3000000 bps).
I found it by adding logs to the method controlTransfer() (and building the ROM), and using the apk [Serial USB Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_usb_terminal&hl=en) from google play.